# How to set Image width 1/2 of default without using javascript

Tags: html, css, image, width

I am going to show image .5 times smaller than normal.
Normal code

```
<img src = "./bk.jpg"/>
```

Tried this one

```
<img src = "./bk.jpg" width = "50%" height = "50%"/>
```

But this width is parent `<div>`'s 50% not default width's 50%.
I can do it in javascript like below

```
img = getElementById();
img.onload = function(){
 img.width /= 2;
 ...
}
```

But I think it can be done only using css.
Please any kind of help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the portion of css that you need

```
img {
 -webkit-transform: scale(0.5); /* Saf3.1+, Chrome */
 -moz-transform: scale(0.5); /* FF3.5+ */
  -ms-transform: scale(0.5); /* IE9 */
   -o-transform: scale(0.5); /* Opera 10.5+ */
      transform: scale(0.5);
}​
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using css  scale property

```css
.half{
  -ms-transform: scale(0.5);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
  transform:scale(0.5);
}
```

```html
<img src = "http://lorempixel.com/200/200/"/>
<img src = "http://lorempixel.com/200/200/" class="half"/>
```